# Outer normal of interval

Tags: real-analysis

Sorry, this might be a stupid question, but am I right with the following:

Let $W$ be a function in one dimension, i.e. $W=W(x)$ a solution of an ODE fulfilling Neumann boundary conditions $\frac{\partial W}{\partial n}=0$ on $\partial\Omega$.

Let, for example, $\Omega=(0,a), a>0$. Am I right that

Then $n(0)=(-1,0), n(a)=(1,0)$ and
$$
\nabla W(0)\cdot n(0)=-W'(0),~~\nabla W(a)\cdot n(a)=W'(a)
$$

and hence the boundary condition yields
$$
W'(0)=0,~W'(a)=0?
$$

Comment: You mean to apply Stoke's theorem to the one-dimensional case to get the fundamental theorem of calculus, correct? Anyway I encourage you to read chapter 10 of Bressoud's "second year calculus" -- it should answer your questions.

Comment: No, nothing such complicated. I just mean Neumann-boundary conditions